# Can't connect to mysql database using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use entity framework, but I can't connect to my database.

Steps I have followed:

1. Add ADO.NET entity data model and select Mysql, input the correct
   data, testing connection and then selecting the database table I
   wanted
2. Visual Studio created a file named "DatabaseContext" and a
   file for each table selected.

DatabaseContext:

```
    namespace TranscoopTrips.Database
    {
        using System.Data.Entity;

        public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
        {
             public DatabaseContext()
             : base("name=Database1")
             {
             }

    public virtual DbSet<address> addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<driver> drivers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<journey> journeys { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<vehicle> vehicles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<expeditionpoint> expeditionpoints { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .HasMany(e => e.expeditionpoints)
            .WithOptional(e => e.address)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.fk_address)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<driver>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<driver>()
            .Property(e => e.surname)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<driver>()
            .HasMany(e => e.journeys)
            .WithRequired(e => e.driver)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.fk_driver);

        modelBuilder.Entity<journey>()
            .Property(e => e.measureunit)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<journey>()
            .Property(e => e.customer)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<journey>()
            .HasMany(e => e.expeditionpoints)
            .WithOptional(e => e.journey)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.fk_journey)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<vehicle>()
            .Property(e => e.plate)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<vehicle>()
            .HasMany(e => e.journeys)
            .WithRequired(e => e.vehicle)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.fk_vehicle);
        }
      }
    }
```

Example of class generated automatically:

```
namespace TranscoopTrips.Database
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("transcooptrips.driver")]
public partial class driver
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public driver()
    {
        journeys = new HashSet<journey>();
    }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(65535)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(65535)]
    public string surname { get; set; }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<journey> journeys { get; set; }
}
}
```

3. Tried to connect to the database in the main program

   ```
       using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
       {

           Console.Write(db.Database.Connection.State); //return always "Closed"
           Console.WriteLine();
       }
   ```

4: Connection string created by visual studio

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=asdasdasd;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=transcooptrips" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

[image: DatabaseContext]
[image: Connection string inside config file]
[image: Code used to prove that can't connect]
[image: Files automatically created by Visual Studio]

The output of  `Console.Write(db.Database.Connection.State);` is always "Closed".

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Instead of posting screen captures you really should just copy and paste code into the question.

Comment: Oh, ok, no problem. I thought the screenshot was better because the code is all autogenerated

Comment: Added the code too now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from another forum someone had the same problem and this was the solution for it:

Install Nuget Package:

Install-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.9.9
Install MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6   - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Changes in Web.Config

```
<EntityFramework>
```

to:

```
<EntityFramework codeConfigurationType = "MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
```

Add (** your information **):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="**YourContextName**" connectionString="server=**xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**;port=3306;user id=**your user**;password=**your password**;database=**your database**" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Restart Visual Studio

My Settings:
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
- Dot Net Framework 4.5.2
- Asp.Net MVC 5.2.3.0
- MySql Server 5.6

Comment: I have reinstalled Visual studio and Mysql server and now works fine. Thanks for the help, don't know what the problem was, but a clean setup solved it.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that @Fanto88

Answer (score 0):

A quick suggestion:

1. Check if your sql services are running or not.
2. Check if the database name is correct or not - it seems your actual database name is "transcooptrips" and you have passed "name=Database1" to the base class. The most preferred way to define such constants is in appsettings.json.

   public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
           {
                public DatabaseContext()
                : base("name=Database1")
                {
                }

Comment: public DatabaseContext (DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext > options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but mysql service is running fine. Name=Database1 refers to the connection string named Database1 that actually has all the correct parameters